# 'cannot deserialize json object into type System.Drawing.Color'

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize JSON using Newtonsoft.

Part of the JSON is a Color object, and I am getting an error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Drawing.Color' because the type requires a JSON string value to deserialize correctly.

This line throws the error:

```
var val = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Equipment>>(json);
```

Here is a sample of the JSON: (it is a very long JSON string so I only included a snippet

```
{"Number":"ORD201312130014.OP10",
"Type":"RoughMill",
"JobNumber":"OP10",
"Status":{
  "Name":"Initial",
  "Type":1,"Color":{
    "R":0,
    "G":0,
    "B":0,
    "A":0,
    "IsKnownColor":false,
    "IsEmpty":true,
    "IsNamedColor":false,
    "IsSystemColor":false,
    "Name":"0"
  }
 ....
```

Comment: Try to first _serialize_ a Color so you can see what format it is expecting.

Comment: Preet, I need to deserialize Json, the answer you gave me was about xml serialization.