# JavaScriptSerializer is not deserializing System.Drawing.Color. How to deserialize Color object?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have serialized System.Drawing.Color in JSON using JavaScriptSerializer, but when i try to de-serialize it, it returns Color object with All the values 0.

Sample JSON is as below.

```
{
    "A":255,
    "B":0,
    "G":165,
    "IsEmpty":false,
    "IsKnownColor":true,
    "IsNamedColor":true,
    "IsSystemColor":false,
    "Name":"Orange",
    "R":255
}
```

Here is the screen shot of how deserialized object looks like.

[image]

Then i tried using JSON.net(newtonsoft.json) library. It gives me below error.

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Drawing.Color' because the type requires a JSON string value to deserialize correctly.
```

Is there any way of deserialzing JSON to color object.i have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667981/cannot-deserialize-json-object-into-type-system-drawing-color) similar question without any answere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since i had very complex JSON. I achieved deserialization using `Color.FromArgb` and `CustomCreationConverter`. Here is how i made it using Json.net library.

I created a class which is responsible for handling deserialization for System.Drawing.Color class from JSON string. you can find [simple example](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/DeserializeCustomCreationConverter.htm) at JSON.net site.

```
public class ColorConverter : CustomCreationConverter<Color>
{
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }
    public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }
    public ColorConverter(){ }
    public override Color Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new Color();
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        Color target = Create(objectType);
        target = Color.FromArgb(jObject["A"].Value<Int32>(), jObject["R"].Value<Int32>(), jObject["G"].Value<Int32>(), jObject["B"].Value<Int32>());
        return target;
    }
}
```

When deserializing pass instance of class that you have created to handle custom deserialization logic

```
MyModelName obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModelName>(json, new ColorConverter());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml` to translate color instances to a hex string that represents a color in html and deserialize it with `ColorTranslator.FromHtml` as suggested at [Best solution for XmlSerializer and System.Drawing.Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376234/best-solution-for-xmlserializer-and-system-drawing-color)

Comment: i have used Color object in may places it is not feasible to write  `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml` or `ColorTranslator.FromHtml`.

Answer (score 0):

Json.NET serializes `System.Drawing.Color` just fine.

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(169, 170, 171, 172);
Console.WriteLine(c); //Color [A=169, R=170, G=171, B=172]
string colorStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c);
Console.WriteLine(colorStr); //"169, 170, 171, 172"
Color c1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Color>(colorStr);
Console.WriteLine(c1); //Color [A=169, R=170, G=171, B=172]
```

Tested against `Json.NET 6.0.3`

Comment: I have tried that,to me it returns name of color like `Orange` and not values of ARGB